# Datareader and list

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net

I am trying to create a list as below and updating it with values from the datareader. I need help in writing the code to update this list from the data reader.

```
internal IList<FilingDto> LoadStatusDtofromReader(IDataReader reader)
        {
            IList<FilingDto> filingstatus = new List<FilingDto>();

            while (reader !=null && reader.Read())
             {
                var dto = new FilingDto();
                var Year = (Decimal)reader["Year"];
                dto = new FilingDto()
                {

                    Controllerid = (Guid)reader["Collectorid"],
                    Status = DBNull.Value.Equals(reader["Status"]) ? string.Empty : reader["Status"].ToString(),
                    Year = Convert.ToInt32(Year),
                    Level = DBNull.Value.Equals(reader["Level"]) ? string.Empty : reader["ServiceLevel"].ToString()
                };

                filingstatus.Add(dto);
            }

            return status;
        }
```

The code to read from the datareader is as below but i am stuck in between please help me complete this

```
DataTable FilingStatus = new DataTable("FilingStatus");
                SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connectionstring"].ConnectionString);
                sqlcon.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Collectorid, Status, Year, Level from dbo.abc", sqlcon);

                using (IDataReader dr =
```

Comment: Code is correct. But you should return 'filingstatus' not 'status'.

Comment: Have you read the documentation and examples on the Datareader class?  [Msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) has examples...

Comment: You are returning a variable `status` that is not declared. Please post something that has at least a chance to compile. Also, why do you declare a `DataTable` when you want to use a `DataReader`? Have a look at [`SqlCommand.ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should invoke ExecuteReader on SqlCommand object

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Collectorid, Status, Year, Level from dbo.abc", sqlcon);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                        reader[0], reader[1]));
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // Always call Close when done reading.
                reader.Close();
            }
```

I suggest to use ORM like Entity framework instead ADO.NET

Comment: I need to add the values into my list and not write it as an output. Hoe do i go about doing that.

Comment: I need to add the values from this table into my list. Please help me on that

Comment: You don't have to explicitly call .Close() if you use the 'using' keyword like.. "using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {...} "

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    DataTable FilingStatus = new DataTable("FilingStatus");
    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CentralW2Database"].ConnectionString); 
    sqlcon.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select CollectorGuid, FileStatus,FilingYear, ServiceLevel from dbo.FilingRequestQueue", sqlcon);

    using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
    {
       IList<FilingDto> list = LoadStatusDtofromReader(dr);
    }

    internal IList<FilingDto> LoadStatusDtofromReader(IDataReader reader)
    {
        var filingstatus = new List<FilingDto>();

        while (reader != null && reader.Read())
        {
            var dto = new FilingDto
            {
                Controllerid = (Guid)reader["Collectorid"],
                Status = DBNull.Value.Equals(reader["Status"]) ? string.Empty : reader["Status"].ToString(),
                Year = Convert.ToInt32((Decimal)reader["Year"]),
                Level = DBNull.Value.Equals(reader["Level"]) ? string.Empty : reader["ServiceLevel"].ToString()
            };

            filingstatus.Add(dto);
        }

        return filingstatus;
    }
```

Comment: ok i got to know about creating the list but how do i read values from my datareader into this list
SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connectionstring"].ConnectionString);
                sqlcon.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Collectorid, Status, Year, Level from dbo.abc", sqlcon);

                using (IDataReader dr =

Comment: Thanks for this. BUt now can you help me read the values from the data reader populate the list

SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CentralW2Database"].ConnectionString);
            sqlcon.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select CollectorGuid, FileStatus,FilingYear, ServiceLevel from dbo.FilingRequestQueue", sqlcon);

            IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {

I am stuck a this point. How to populate the list

Comment: Exactly like you are doing it.  filingstatus.Add(dto);

Answer (score 0):

If you can reuse the original function just do

```
using (DataReader dr = cme.ExecuteReader()) 
{
    IList<FilingDto> list = LoadStatusDtofromReader(dr);
}
```